# javascript with json and google chart using while loop

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

i started to work on javascript reading a local json file and am trying to get it into a google chart but I'm having an issue with the while loop as noted below in my error comment. Var c calls a function to count the data rows in the json file.

```
 function drawChart() {
    var soData = JSON.parse(staffOrders);
    var i = 0;
    var c = getRowCount(); //returns 5

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Staff');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Orders Filled');
    //works
    //data.addRows([
      //['John', 3],
      //['Tommy', 1],
      //['Ken', 1],
      //['Sally', 1],
      //["Missy", 2]
    //]);

    //works
    data.addRows([
        [soData[0].staffName, Number(soData[0].orders)],
        [soData[1].staffName, Number(soData[1].orders)],
        [soData[2].staffName, Number(soData[2].orders)],
        [soData[3].staffName, Number(soData[3].orders)],
        [soData[4].staffName, Number(soData[4].orders)]
    ]);

    //***error - below doesn't render
    //also need to remove comma in last row as it isn't needed
    //data.addRows([
        //while (i <= c) {
            //[soData[i].staffName, Number(soData[i].orders)],
            //i++;
        //}
    //]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to send a while loop into data.addRows(). Move the function call into the while loop

```
while (i <= c) {
    data.addRows([[soData[i].staffName, Number(soData[i].orders)]]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: no luck - still not rendering; i tried that earlier in a different manner.